# Replace MSMQ system with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to replace a complicated Messaging system build using MSMQ with RabbitMQ. The MSMQ is sending Message and using the XMLMessageFormatter and BinaryMessageFormatter Based on System.Messaging namespace.

I am wondering does RabbitMQ support sending the Message  based on System.Messaging namespace or how can I achieve that with minimum changing the current code in the system.

I do know Rabbit suppport xml ,json format.

Any suggestions or ideas on convert form MSMQ to RabbitMq  would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is a great use case for https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/bridge/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ doesnt support a messaging format. You send data to it in a byte array. How you choose to represent your data (JSON, XML etc) before converting to a byte array is entirely up to you.

So you should be able to keep on using the exact same message format. Just add as step to convert from/to byte array.